# Styling features loaded from mongoDB geojson

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

I have a map with a layer containing annotations made by a user stored in geojson format in a mongoDB database.

When the page loads I create a vector layer to display the annotations as such:

```
features = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(response);
var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
      source: new ol.source.Vector({features: features})
});
```

This works fine and I am able to display all the features in the default styling.
Each feature does however have a styling property associated with it.
How do I go through all the features in the layer that I have created and change each annotation to the correct style?

I have tried creating a custom styling function when making the layer like so:

```
var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
      source: new ol.source.Vector({features: features})
      style: customStyleFunction
});
```

Though this works, the customStyleFunction is run each time I pan, zoom etc. I only wish for the styling to be applied once when the data is imported.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Each feature

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
layer.getSource().on('addfeature', function(feature) {
  feature.setStyle(customStyleFunction(feature));
});
```